# Chrome extension won't open due to iframe?

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to write a Chrome extension to access Steam's web chat by using an iFrame inside a popup:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
   ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="http://steamcommunity.com/chat/" width="779" height="534" frameborder="0"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is, when I click the button, no pop-up appears. The part I can't understand is if I replace the iFrame's target to some other website using something like:

```
<iframe src="http://bing.com" width="779" height="534" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Then it works fine. It even works if I use the Bing iFrame to navigate to the chat webpage. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Upon further investigation, Steam does seem to be down. It'll work later.

Answer (score 0):

The popup won't appear until the page loads, Steam might just be super slow OR it just won't work due to settings that were set by Steam.